# Expand a range which looks like: "1-3,6,8-10" to [1,2,3, 6, 8,9,10]

Tags: python

I am trying to add an option to my program which allow the user to choose which steps of the program he wants to do.

I would like to be able to parse a string like `"1-3,6,8-10"` and get  `[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]`.

Do you know if something in Python which is doing that already exists ?

Comment: I am always impressed by how fast I get an answer here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function does what you asked. It assumes no negative numbers are used, otherwise it needs some changes to support that case.

```
def mixrange(s):
    r = []
    for i in s.split(','):
        if '-' not in i:
            r.append(int(i))
        else:
            l,h = map(int, i.split('-'))
            r+= range(l,h+1)
    return r


print mixrange('1-3,6,8-10')
```

Comment: +1 my version with created list worse. It's easy to create generator from your version also

Answer (score 6):

One way using list comprehensions:

```
s = "1-3,6,8-10"
x = [ss.split('-') for ss in s.split(',')]
x = [range(int(i[0]),int(i[1])+1) if len(i) == 2 else i for i in x]
print([int(item) for sublist in x for item in sublist])
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

No builtin function as such, but can be done using `xrange` and generators:

```
from itertools import chain

s = "1-3,6,8-10"
spans = (el.partition('-')[::2] for el in s.split(','))
ranges = (xrange(int(s), int(e) + 1 if e else int(s) + 1) for s, e in spans)
all_nums = chain.from_iterable(ranges) # loop over, or materialse using `list`
# [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Obligatory Python 3 update -- use range() instead of xrange()

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '1-3,6,8-10,13-16'
temp = [x.split('-') if '-' in x else x for x in s.split(',')]
# temp = [['1', '3'], '6', ['8', '10'], ['13', '16']]
res = []
for l in temp:
    if isinstance(l, list):
        a, b = map(int, l)
        res += list(range(a, b + 1))
    else:
        res.append(int(l))

 # res = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little function I just created:

```
def expand(st):
    res = []
    for item in st.split(','):
        if '-' in item:
            temp = map(int, item.split('-'))
            res.extend(range(temp[0], temp[1]+1))
        else:
            res.append(int(item))
    return res

s = '1-3,6,8-10'
print expand(s)
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: It's buggy, what if the range string is '10,11'?

Comment: expand('10,11') IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think you meant `if '-' in item:`, otherwise your function will fail.

Comment: @LtWorf Ugh. I should sleep

Answer (score 0):

```
def parseIntSet(nputstr=""):
  selection = set()
  invalid = set()
  # tokens are comma seperated values
  tokens = [x.strip() for x in nputstr.split(',')]
  for i in tokens:
     try:
        # typically tokens are plain old integers
        selection.add(int(i))
     except:
        # if not, then it might be a range
        try:
           token = [int(k.strip()) for k in i.split('-')]
           if len(token) > 1:
              token.sort()
              # we have items seperated by a dash
              # try to build a valid range
              first = token[0]
              last = token[len(token)-1]
              for x in range(first, last+1):
                 selection.add(x)
        except:
           # not an int and not a range...
           invalid.add(i)
  # Report invalid tokens before returning valid selection
  print "Invalid set: " + str(invalid)
  return selection
```

Via: [Parsing a list of numbers in Python](http://thoughtsbyclayg.blogspot.com/2008/10/parsing-list-of-numbers-in-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, one line proof of concept anyone?

EDIT: Improved version

```
import itertools
s = "1-3,6,8-10"

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(range(int(ranges[0]), int(ranges[1])+1) for ranges in ((el+[el[0]])[:2] for el in (miniRange.split('-') for miniRange in s.split(','))))))
```

Now split on several lines for readability:

```
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    range(
        int(ranges[0]),
        int(ranges[1])+1
    )
    for ranges in 
        (
            (el+[el[0]])[:2] # Allows to get rid of the ternary condition by always adding a duplicate of the first element if it is alone
            for el in
            (miniRange.split('-') for miniRange in s.split(','))
        )
)))
```