# Expand an alphanumeric range which looks like A1-A4

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add a function to my program in python which expand alphanumeric string ranges.

```
input = "A1-A4"
```

And create an expanded range as a list:

```
output = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
```

I have looked at previous similar answers for expanding numeric ranges in: [Expand a range which looks like: "1-3,6,8-10" to [1,2,3, 6, 8,9,10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759512/expand-a-range-which-looks-like-1-3-6-8-10-to-1-2-3-6-8-9-10). However the solutions provided aren't able to handle alphanumeric ranges.

I have tried extracting the first character using regex and combining with Austin's below (didn't ask question correctly first time around):

```
str = 'B1-B4'
word1 = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", str))
letter=word1[0]
ranges = [int(s) for s in str if s.isdigit()]
new_string=([f'letter{i}' for i in range(ranges[0], ranges[1]+1)])
```

However, the output is not pulling through the letter. I also don't think the process above is the most logical.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes, but this is probably not what you wanted to ask. I suggest providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you should've posted what you tried. The code, I mean.

Comment: @Mr.T I've read the example and changed the format of my question accordingly. Will keep in mind in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses `regex` to expand range:

```
import re

str = 'A1-A4'
chr = str[0]
ranges = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', str)))
print([f'{chr}{i}' for i in range(ranges[0], ranges[1]+1)])

# ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Before it didn't work for multiple digit numbers. Now it does.:)

Comment: I thought this solved my problem but realised I didn't ask the question correctly. Have tried a work around using your elegant solution.

Comment: Not quite. I need to be able any combination of alphanumeric ranges i.e. X98-X99 or C10-C15

Comment: @whiskey_14 Before posting an update, just asking is there any other special cases to incorporate?

Comment: The only other condition which would be helpful is if it works for multiple digits as well. Other than that no. All strings follow same format as 'one letter' + '2/3 digits'. (the letter will always be the same)

Comment: See the answer. Works for any number of digits.

Comment: Great, I made a slight change to line 5 to `ranges = list(map(int, re.findall(r'(\d+)', str)))` so it could handle any A-Z character. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that uses a pattern matching both the letters and digits, including that the letters are the same, and then applies them with a substitution function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s="Q4-Q6 and X3-X5"
>>> re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)-\1(\d+)", (
...   lambda m: ','.join(m.group(1)+str(i)
...     for i in range(int(m.group(2)),int(m.group(3))+1))
...   ), s)
'Q4,Q5,Q6 and X3,X4,X5'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
input = "A1-A4"
l = input[1:].split('-')
['A'+str(x) for x in range(int(l[0]), int(l[1][1:])+1)]
```

First the string is split into 2 parts using the `-` as the delimiter. Then the number p of both the fragments

This method would work even if the input was

```
input = "A23-A29"
```

in which case the output would be

```
['A23', 'A24', 'A25', 'A26', 'A27', 'A28', 'A29']
```

Change the letter as you need.